# Having a function argument determine from which object another function should be called

Tags: javascript

My goal is to develop a function which would allow me to **exchange any item between any two collections of items** in the context of a simple JS/HTML5 game .

The logic is presented below, with the variables hardcoded instead of defined as function arguments.

```
function InventoryToWarehouse(draggedItemID) {
  var howMany = prompt("How many items do you want to store in the warehouse?",0);

  if(Game.heroInventory.hasItem(draggedItemID,howMany)) {
    Game.heroInventory.removeItem(draggedItemID,howMany, "inventory");
    Game.warehouse.addItem(draggedItemID,howMany,"warehouse");
  } else { alert("Not enough items in the inventory!"); 
}
```

The function utilizes three smaller functions from the inventory management system: hasItem, addItem and removeItem. Code below:

```
Inventory = function(){
  var self = {
    items:[] //{id:"itemId",quantity:1}
  }
  self.addItem = function(id,quantity,whereToRender){
    for(var i = 0 ; i < self.items.length; i++){
      if(self.items[i].id === id){
        self.items[i].quantity += quantity;
        self.refreshRender(whereToRender);
        return;
      }
    }
    self.items.push({id:id,quantity:quantity});
    self.refreshRender(whereToRender);
  }

  self.removeItem = function(id,quantity,whereToRender){
    for(var i = 0 ; i < self.items.length; i++){
      if(self.items[i].id === id){
        self.items[i].quantity -= quantity;
        if(self.items[i].quantity <= 0)
          self.items.splice(i,1);
          self.refreshRender(whereToRender);
          return;
        }
      }    
    }

  self.hasItem = function(id,quantity){
    for(var i = 0 ; i < self.items.length; i++){
      if(self.items[i].id === id){
        return self.items[i].quantity >= quantity;
      }
    }  
    return false;
  }

  self.refreshRender = function(whereToRender){
    var str = "";
    for(var i = 0 ; i < self.items.length; i++){
      let item = Item.List[self.items[i].id];
      let onclick = "Item.List['" + item.id + "'].event()";
      str += "<button onclick=\"" + onclick + "\">" + item.name + " x" + self.items[i].quantity + "</button><br>";
    }

    if(whereToRender=="inventory"){document.getElementById("inventory").innerHTML = str;}
  }

return self;
}
```

They inventory management functions **work perfectly as long as the object for which they are to be performed is hard-coded** - just as in case of the InventoryToWarehouse() above.

Is there a way to create a **more general/ customizable version** of the InventoryToWarehouse() function? One **whose arguments would determine** between which item collections is the exchange supposed to take place?

I tried the following - but it didn't work:

```
function exchangeItemsBetweenCollections(collectionGiving, collectionReceiving) {

  var howMany = prompt("How many items do you want to store in the warehouse?",0);

  if(collectionGiving.hasItem(draggedItemID,howMany))   {
    collectionGiving.removeItem(draggedItemID,howMany, "inventory");
    collectionReceiving.addItem(draggedItemID,howMany,"warehouse"); 
  } else {alert("Not enough items in the inventory!")}
}
```

The error I keep receiving is: **collectionGiving.hasItem is not a function**.
Would anyone please care to:

1. Help me fix the code
2. Explain me what I was doing wrong
3. Show me where can I learn more about what's needed to not make similar mistakes in the future

?

Comment: where is `exchangeItemsBetweenCollections` being called, you are not initializing `Inventory`, unless i did something wrong while indenting, then you also need a `}` in `self.removeItem` lastly do not use `self` as it is a reserved keyword

Comment: @Pavlo

`exchangeItemsBetweenCollections` is called on its own, i.e. not as part of any other function. /////

This is not the complete code of the project. `Game.heroInventory.` and `Game.warehouse` are initialized as `= new Inventory();` elsewhere. /////

All inventory management functions (`addItem, removeItem, hasItem`) work fine on their own when called referencing one of the `Inventory` objects (e.g. `Game.heroInventory.hasItem(draggedItemID,howMany);`). No brackets are missing - maybe I've made a mistake while copy-pasting./////

Does that help you answer my original question?

Comment: Please edit to show how `exchangeItemsBetweenCollections` is being called, maybe one of the collections are undefined. You could try to `console.log(collectionGiving)` and `console.log(collectionReceiving)`